# Find and select a string

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the string `"P1"` in worksheet `Sheet1` for a macro I am making. I can't seem to find how to do this after searching for a while. Anything that was suggested didn't work. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly have you already tried?  Is "P1" always going to be in a specific column or anywhere on sheet1?  What exactly do you want to do with the cell once you find "P1"?  Select it, manipulate it, delete it, etc.  Give us a few more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `Find()` function:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="P1")

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    r.Select
    MsgBox "First found at " & r.Address
End If
```

Comment: when I run this, I get the error "Object required" ?

Comment: Do you have a `Sheet1` object? What's the name of your worksheet? We can do it that way, too.

Comment: The debug points to this part of the code "Set r = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="P1")
"